# Detect same item in a list discord python JSON file

Tags: discord.py

In discord PY I have a JSON file that I write to when I add something. It adds it to a list.

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def add(self, ctx, itemlist, *, item):
        """Usage: `!add <list> <item>`"""
        with open("list.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        try:
            data[itemlist].append(item)
        except KeyError:
            data[itemlist] = [item]
        with open("list.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        await ctx.send("Succesfully added '{}' to the list '{}'".format(item, itemlist))
```

I want to know how I could go about detecting if the same item already exists in a list, and in an efficient way, add the amount of the duplicates afterwards.

For example, if someone adds an apple:
!add list apple
When you view the list, it will say:
apple

Now when someone does !add list apple again, it'll instead show
apple x2

Comment: Using `.count(item)` on a list returns number of occurrences of `item` in the list.
To see if an item is in the list, you can try `if item in list : #do x`

Comment: I can manage to return the count of the number of items, but how would I go about removing the item from the list, and re-adding it with the x(count) on it?
Im using .format 
although some error happens where it adds the list twice

Comment: I believe a dictionary would be useful in such a case, every time an item is added you can update the key with the new count (value), `items = {'apple' : 1,...}`.  Similar to a list , you can do `key in dict` to see if `key` exists in the dictionary, if it doesn't simply create a key-value pair of an item with a single occurance `items['apple'] = 1 `